# Time Machine: exclude folders with same name, now AND in the future

Tags: time-machine

I want to exclude backup of proxy media in Final Cut Pro. This media is located in:

```
~/Movies/Final Cut Events/[Event Folder]/Transcoded Media/Proxy Media
```

Problem is, when I create a new [Event Folder] it creates a new directory named "Proxy Media" which has to be manually omitted from Time Machine each time. I'd like to automate this process.

I've looked at *tmutil* in the command line, but I don't think that will do it.

Answer (score 6):

You could save a property list like this as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/excludefinalcut.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>EnableGlobbing</key>
  <true/> <!-- enable wildcard and tilde expansion for ProgramArguments -->
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>excludefinalcut</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>tmutil</string>
    <string>addexclusion</string>
    <string>~/Movies/Final Cut Events/*/Transcoded Media/Proxy Media</string>
  </array>
  <key>WatchPaths</key>
  <array>
    <string>~/Movies/Final Cut Events</string>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then load the plist by running `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/excludefinalcut.plist`.

`tmutil addexclusion` gives files a `com.apple.metadata:com_apple_backup_excludeItem` extended attribute. `sudo tmutil addexclusion -p` would add files to the `SkipPaths` dictionary in `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist` that is also modified by System Preferences.

Comment: Note: as of MacOS 10.10, the `EnableGlobbing` flag no longer works. But, you can achieve something similar by putting your `tmutil` command inside a shell script file, and then from the launch agent plist above, simply use the command `bash`, with program arguments `-c` and then the path to your script file. A wildcard inside the script's `tmutil` command will be properly respected and expanded.