# How to stop Time Machine backing up log files inside application containers?

Tags: macos, time-machine

Time Machine does not backup log files in `~/Library/Logs`

But it *does* backup logs files within application containers.  For example, log files in the folder `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Logs/Mail`.

My Mail and OneDrive logs are currently adding about 2 GB per backup.

I could manually exclude each of `~/Library/Containers/*/Data/Library/Logs` but that is a lot of exclusions and would be a list which needs addition whenever I install a new app.

The `~/Library/Containers/*` folders were introduced to support sandboxing applications, but Time Machine seems to have not kept up with these changes.

Is there a better way of telling Time Machine to not backup the `/Log` folders within Containers?

I am using OS X Yosemite 10.10.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar need and using a combination of [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/108890/147375) and [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/153149/147375) I came up with the following solution.

Create a property list (e.g. `~/Library/LaunchAgents/excludeLogFiles.plist`) which will be loaded with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/excludeLogFiles.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>excludeLogFiles</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/bin/zsh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>tmutil addexclusion /Users/user/Library/Containers/**/Data/Library/Logs</string>
  </array>
  <key>WatchPaths</key>
  <array>
    <string>/Users/user/Library/Containers</string>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Instead of using `EnableGlobbing`, which hasn't been supported since OS X 10.10 ([ref](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.launchd.devel/56)), the path gets expanded by the program calling `/bin/zsh <args>`.

A couple of things I found while experimenting:

1. The `**` glob works with `zsh` but not `bash`
2. Using `~` should work in the path for `ProgramArguments` but I don't know if the same trick can be used for `WatchPath`. Hard-coding the user path might be necessary.

Comment: No ~ is not called through zsh - it gets expanded by the program calling /bin/zsh <args>

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've updated the answer to hopefully be correct now.

Comment: You know what?  With Sierra, nearly all my Containers/**/Data/Library/Logs are empty.  So the problem has gone!  Part of the Sierra changes to logging.  But your answer looks correct - I hadn't thought of that method - obvious when you are shown it!  So I will mark it as correct answer to the question for when I asked.

Comment: Thanks.  I used this to exclude sbt generated target dirs with a pattern like: tmutil addexclusion /Users/user/dev/*/target  /Users/user/dev/*/*/target /Users/user/dev/*/*/*/target /Users/user/dev/*/*/*/*/target

Comment: Note that the use of "**/target" was way way slower than explicit use of */*/*

Comment: Note relevant other link here that notes that these excluded directories do now show up in the preferences list, which is kind of scary/dangerous: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/222348/23555

Comment: @Traveler: That was my use case as well (maven vs sbt), but speed was less of a concern than making sure I included all possible target directories, present and future. Hence my preference for /**/.